# ios load an image from docDir into UIimagview - viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a group of images saved in my DOcuments folder of the app. I got it to save to that location, I am having trouble loading from that location.

I got the UIimageView working hardcoded with images I dragged to a folder in the project with the code below in the viewDidLoad() method and when i ran the simulator it appeared.

```
UIImageView *bottomPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pants.png"]];
bottomPic.frame = CGRectMake(65, 279, 200, 250);
[self.view addSubview:bottomPic];
[bottomPic release];
```

However when I want to load the image from the Documents Directory nothing loads - Am confused and couldn't find any exact information to help me out on this situation.. This is currently what I have and when I run it doesn't throw any errors but no image appears. Am I missing something in my code? (I'm new to objective-c!)

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bottom1A2A6520-F556-436F-A1BC-D430223DC890-33098-00014708AE7E370F.png"]];


UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

UIImageView *bottomPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:path]];
bottomPic.frame = CGRectMake(65, 279, 200, 250);
[bottomPic setImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:bottomPic];
[bottomPic release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A path is a path and an image is an image.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

UIImageView *bottomPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Comment: I'm confused, so how do I get it to display the image that the path leads to?

Comment: @user3312008 That's what he's just shown you how to do. `imageWithContentsOfFile:` returns a UIImage object, which you then apply to the image view. `initWithImage:` takes a UIImage object as a parameter, not an NSString.

Comment: But when i run it, the image still doesnt appear?

Comment: If this does not show an image then set a breakpoint on the second line and double check whether `image` is `nil` or not. If it is `nil` then there is something wrong with your `path`. If it references to an object of type `UIImage` then it should display nicely. However, when you want it in one line then do this: `UIImageView *bottomPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];` Then your mistake was to use ?imageNamed` followed by a path. `imageNamed` is to be followed by a filename only while the file is supposed to be part of the bundle.

Comment: However, I strongly suggest not having everything in one line. If you do that then debugging becomes more difficult. And you don't win anything.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! my Path was wrong Should have been NSDocumentsDirectory not NSDocumentationDirectory!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues. Try this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bottom1A2A6520-F556-436F-A1BC-D430223DC890-33098-00014708AE7E370F.png"];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImageView *bottomPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
bottomPic.frame = CGRectMake(65, 279, 200, 250);
[self.view addSubview:bottomPic];
[bottomPic release];
```

Unrelated to the problem, you were needlessly using `stringWithFormat:`.

The real problem was creating the `UIImageView` with an unneeded image using `imageNamed:`.

If this doesn't work then verify that `path` actually represents a file that really exists in the Documents folder. Verify `image` isn't `nil`.

Also consider use ARC (automatic reference counting) to make your life a lot easier.

Update: It appears you needed `NSDocumentDirectory` instead of `NSDocumentationDirectory`.